# Question about linear_congruential_engine::min()

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, std

The standard C++ library provides class template `linear_congruential_engine`. Given the template parameters `a`, `c`, `m`, this engine produces unsigned integer numbers by using the following formula:

```
x_{i+1} = (a * x_{i} + c) % m
```

For instance, the execution of

```
#define _a 2
#define _c 0
#define _m 16

typedef std::linear_congruential_engine<unsigned int, _a, _c, _m> T;
T lce; // Default seed equals 1

for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
   std::cout << lce() << " ";
std::cout << std::endl;
```

unsurprisingly produces the following output:

```
2 4 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

So, the minimum of this sequence equals 0. However, according to ISO-IEC-14882-2017-5 [[rand.eng.lcong]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/rand.eng.lcong), `lce.min()` shall return 1 if `c == 0`:

> ```
> static constexpr result_type min() { return c == 0u ? 1u: 0u; }
> ```

Could anybody explain to me why `lce.min()` is greater than the actual minimal value in this case?

Comment: It seems like that `min` makes *except* if the generator only returns an infinite sequence of zero. `min` is one if and only if `c == 0`, in which case any time the generator reaches the state `0` it will always get stuck there. It would be reasonable for the language to ignore that exceptional case. An RNG that always returns zero probably isn't deserving of the name. But I can't find any language that expresses that, so it might be implied (in that this LCE isn't really a PRNG), it might be an omission or I might have just missed it.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Then why doesn't `min()` just always return 0?  This is special cased, so there has to be some subtlety involved ...

Comment: @L.F. This is probably a case of the 90-10 principal. When `c == 0` the state of the generator can't be zero without getting stuck so the minimum is easily deduced to be `1`. Assuming you don't produce a generator that always returns `0`, it will always return *at least* `1` when `c == 0`. Otherwise, with a non-zero `c`, the generator's state can be zero without getting stuck. So it can produce `0` in a typical use case. Using this reasoning you get a `min` that produces *some* information for almost not effort (90-10 principal).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Indeed.  I neglected the case where the engine doesn't get stuck at 0.  Sounds like *the* answer.  (BTW, this explanation of the 90-10 principle amazed me!  I always thought it is about reaction to bad events, but anyway ...)

Comment: @L.F. My problem with posting this as an answer is it seems incomplete. I don't understand why the language wouldn't either explicitly single out this case or take it into account. Since it has the language-lawyer tag, that part of the answer sounds important to me.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux The thing that also bothers me is that `min` and `max` estimations are not accurate anyway. If we put `a=2`, `c=0` and `m=6`, the results produced by LCE will be equal to 0, 2, or 4 for any seed. What I am trying to say is that `lce.min()` is not attained if we exclude 0 from this set. Meanwhile, [rand.req.urng] explicitly says that "`G::min() denotes the least value potentially returned by `operator()``".